# PL/SQL Cursor Use Parameter As A Column Name

Tags: parameters, plsql, cursor

I am working with PL/SQL. I am sending some parameters to my procedure. One of these parameters should be a column name. Initially it's a varchar2, but I want to use this in my cursor to reference a column name. How is this possible?

This is what my code looks something like:

```
    PROCEDURE proc_name( x IN VARCHAR2, y IN VARCHAR2 ) IS

      cursor csr IS 
       SELECT * 
       FROM table
       SORT BY x y


     BEGIN 
      for y in csr loop 
        ------
      end loop; 

     END proc_name;
```

I've tried to research this for the last couple of days with no luck. I looked into dynamic SQL, is this the right direction? Doesn't seem to be working for me.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Yes, dynamic SQL is the answer but you are in dangerous SQL injection territory.  Imagine if someone called your procedure like `proc_name ('(select salary from emp where ename = ''My Manager'')'`

Comment: @TonyAndrews - Dangerous to whom? Everybody ought to know what their manager earns!

Comment: @Tony Andrews Would you be able to show me an example please? Everyone that I have tried just hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Do you actually want to "select * from X" or "select X from mytable"?  Your question says column but your example uses a table in FROM clause.

Comment: @TonyAndrews I updated the code above so you can see exactly what I'm trying to do. Trying to sort the table by a given sort column in a given direction. So x is the column name and y is DESC or ASC.

Comment: OK, I have posted an answer for that.  It is still possibly open to SQL injection though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
PROCEDURE proc_name( x IN VARCHAR2, y IN VARCHAR2 ) IS

  rc sys_refcursor;

  r_table table%rowtype;

 BEGIN 
  open rc for
   'SELECT * 
    FROM table
    ORDER BY ' || x || ' ' || y;
  loop
    fetch rc into r_table;
    exit when rc%notfound;
    ------
  end loop; 
  close rc;

 END proc_name;
```

Comment: rable meant to be table. I applied your technique to my procedure and it works! Thank you very much. Not only does it work, but I understand dynamic sql a little better now. Thank you again.